# How to know from where to get header files used in a c program?

Tags: c

I have a project which was implemented in C language some 10 years ago. As it's been a long time, I dont know about dependency libraries required to compile that project so I am getting all 'unresolved external symbol' errors.

How do I know if I have a C file, it has plenty of header files, and then which header file belongs to which library? What are all softwares to be installed for those included header files?

Comment: You make yourself a good coffee and start reading the source code.

Comment: `unresolved external symbol` sounds to me like you compiled successfully, but linking failed. That means, any used header could be found. IMHO there are chances that accompanying libraries are also there. So, try to find the `unresolved external symbol`s in man, google them, or (if nothing else helps) `find`/`nm` (or something similar) might be an option as well.

Answer (score 1):

To have an overview of how the header files are organized in a project, take a look at [**cinclude2dot**](https://www.flourish.org/cinclude2dot/)

it will plot an #include **dependency graph** for your project.

Comment: I am looking from what are the thirdy party modules required to be included to avoid depedency issues